# TableSection Spacing Android Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, tableview

I have 1 `TableView`, 3 `TableSections`. 
In iOS , the `TableSections` have a space between them, this space is not replicated in `Android`, how would I add the space in `Android`? without upsetting the iOS layout.

**My Ideas:**

1. Add a blank, disabled Cell which only shows on Android.
2. Use a grid, which only shows on Android
3. Platform Specific XAML forms, if == Android, use XAML-A if ==iOS use XAML-B
4. Custom renderer. If so, How?

I am open to other ideas or if someone could tell me the recommended way or, which of my ideas to pursue it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Platform Specific code should be your primary option IMO. Maybe some cell margin, that would be greater on Android than on iOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I tried you first idea `Add a blank, disabled Cell which only shows on Android.`, it's a little complex, let's do it step by step:

First, I add a white label at the end of each `TableSection` as space,here is my `Xaml`, remember to set your `tableview.HasUnevenRows="True"`:

```
<ContentPage.Content >
    <TableView Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <TableView.BindingContext>
            <local:Model/>
        </TableView.BindingContext>

        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Getting Started">

                    <SwitchCell Text="New Voice Mail" />
                <SwitchCell Text="New Mail" On="true" />


                <!--use as space-->
                <ViewCell x:Name="cell2">
                    <StackLayout  x:Name="s1">
                        <Label Text="space"
                          TextColor="#f35e20" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  x:Name="spacelabel2"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>

        <TableSection Title="Getting Started22222" >


                <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="left"
                          TextColor="#f35e20" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
                    <Label Text="right"
                          HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                          TextColor="#503026" BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>


                <!--use as space-->
                <ViewCell x:Name="cell1">
                    <StackLayout x:Name="s2">
                        <Label Text="space"
                          TextColor="#f35e20" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" x:Name="spacelabel1"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>

            <TableSection Title="Getting Started33333" >
                <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="left"
                          TextColor="#f35e20" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
                    <Label Text="right"
                          HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                          TextColor="#503026" BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>

    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I gave the `ViewCell` a name like `cell1` and `cell2`, then in the code behind, I use `Device.RuntimePlatform` to distinguish `iOS` or `Android`:

```
 protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                spacelabel1.IsVisible = true;
                spacelabel2.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cell2.Height = 0.01;
                cell1.Height = 0.01;
                cell1.View.IsVisible = false;
                cell2.View.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
```

So, in the iOS, these white labels will not show in this page, in Android, these labels will appear at the end of each section. You can set the label's background color the same as `TableSections`'s color, then it will look like there is a space between them. Reply me if you have any problem.

Comment: Awesome thanks, this solved the issue. I did use a slightly different approach in the code behind though. I set `IsVisible` to false for `iOS`.Tthat is the _only_ thing I set. Is there any reason I shouldn't have done that? or is it just a different road to the same destination?

Comment: @wades Actually, set `IsVisible` to false for `iOS` is enough to make the cells invisible. I set `cell.height = 0.01`  will also make the cell invisible, they are two different ways. I would recommend you to use  `cell.View.IsVisible = false; `.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `PlatformSpecific` code:

```
<YourElement.Margin>
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
       <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,0,0,0" />
       <On Platform="Android, WinPhone, Windows" Value="0,5,0,0" />
       </OnPlatform>
  </YourElement.Margin>
```

Comment: In this case I would need to apply a margin to a `TableSection` which doesn't seem to have the option for a margin